# What's the proper way to unload a common library?

Tags: deployment

I'm trying to deploy my package (via VS 2010) and getting this error.

"Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Error: Cannot add the specified assembly to the global assembly cache: SPSureCommon.dll."

I tried to use GacUtil but it whines about the dll being 'in-use'... so I ran Process Explorer and about 10 processes have loaded the DLL for some reason.

The only way I've figured out how to update these common dlls is to kill every using process, delete it via GacUtil and then reboot the server.

There has to be a better way...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you will need to kill the sharepoint/other processes for the new version to be loaded.

I have a powershell/cmd script that will unload my sharepoint. (shouldnt need to reboot)

```
& iisreset /restart
& net stop sptimerv4
& net start sptimerv4
& net stop sptracev4
& net start sptracev4
```

Add any other processes you need.

Comment: thanks djeeg.

for anyone who needs the same thing.  here is my powerscript for SharePoint 2010 with VS 2010.

iisreset /restart
net stop sptimerv4
net start sptimerv4
net stop sptracev4
net start sptracev4
net stop SPUserCodeV4
net start SPUserCodeV4
net stop WebAnalyticsService
net start WebAnalyticsService
stop-process -name vssphost4